# Sklearn MLP Classifier Hyperparameter Optimization (RandomizedSearchCV)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I have the following parameters set up :

```
parameter_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [(sp_randint(100,600),sp_randint(100,600),), (sp_randint(100,600),)],
    'activation': ['tanh', 'relu', 'logistic'],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'alpha': stats.uniform(0.0001, 0.9),
    'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive']}
```

All the parameters except the hidden_layer_sizes is working as expected. However, fitting this RandomizedSearchCV model and displaying it's verbose text shows that it treats hidden_layer_sizes as :

`hidden_layer_sizes=(<scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object`
and goes on to throw : `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'rv_frozen' and 'int'`

This result is obtained instead of the expected 1 or 2 layer MLP with hidden layer neurons between 100 and 600. Any ideas / other related tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sp_randint` returns an instance of the `rv_discrete` class / a randint object, in order to generate random numbers, the correct syntax should be `sp_randint.rvs(low, high, size)`. 
In order to make it work you need to define the `parameter_space` as below:

`parameter_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [(sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),), 
                                          (sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),)],
    'activation': ['tanh', 'relu', 'logistic'],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'alpha': uniform(0.0001, 0.9),
    'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive']}`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure random values being picked for hidden_layer_sizes for each iteration of the RandomizedSearchCV? Currently, it precomputes these random values once and they remain the same across various iterations

Comment: Do we really want to change the hidden_layer_sizes (structure of MLP) with each iteration for MLP, how would we interpret the reults then? I think it's better to have it  randomly generated once and keep it fixed through all the iterations.